# Django How to display error if the query results are empty

Tags: django, search

I am building a simple app which enables the users to search quotes from db by entering keywords using a form. I would like to return an error if no matching quotes are found for the entered keywords.

Here's the search form:

```
<form action="{% url 'search_results' %}" method="get">
   <input name="q" type="text" placeholder="Search By Keywords" id="q" required />
   <button onClick="{% url 'search_results' %}" class="btn btn-success">Search Quotes</button>
</form>
```

Here's the views.py

```
{% for quotes in object_list %}
    <div class="shadow card"> 
      <div class="card-body">
          <h6 class="card-title">{{ quotes.by }}</h6>
          <p>{{ quotes.quotation }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`for..empty`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#for-empty) loop:

```
{% for quotes in object_list %}
  ...
{% empty %}
  <p>No quotes found</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Selcuk, many thanks for helping me out. I am a sales professional and want to switch to coding so I have started learning django via selft taught online mode. So I really appreciate you taking time out to help me. Thanks again and stay safe